# Grails 3 session and distributed cache using redis

Tags: session, caching, grails

I have been looking around for a way to achieve this and I have not found any authoritative answer making me wonder if this has stopped being the practice when running application on a cluster of 2 or more servers.

I have grails 3.2.2 app that will run on aws. I am using simple form using default spring security plugin `compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'`

I would love to be able to store session in redis for load balancing purpose. Using elastic cache service (redis) on aws.

I would also love to use the same in replacement of ehcache.

So far for session I got

- [spring-session from jeetmp3](https://github.com/jeetmp3/spring-session)
- [grails-redis-session from rpalcolea](https://github.com/rpalcolea/grails-redis-session/)

For caching I got

- [org.grails.plugins:redis:1.6.6](https://grails.org/plugin/redis)
- [org.grails.plugins:cache-redis:1.1.0](http://grails.org/plugin/cache-redis)
- [org.grails.plugins:cache:3.0.3](https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/cache)

Looks like I am really lost on this. Don't know which one to one or which one to use together. I would be very much grateful if someone can point me to the right direction. Any recent documentation or tutorial is welcome.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to install any other plugin but only spring-session with spring security.

this link is exactly what you looking for http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/grails3.html

(As you may know, grails3 is implemented based on springboot, so you can refer the springboot document to solve grails3 problem.)